# Changing UITabBarItem image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have used Storyboard to set up my `UITabBarController` and its corresponding `ViewControllers`. Whenever a tab is deselected, it is gray, when it is selected it has a green tint. I would like one of these `UITabBarItems` to always look the same: i.e. it always has the green tint regardless of whether it is selected or deselected. 
 In addition, the icon image I am using for this `UITabBarItem` already has the green look that I want. This is important because I have tried using this method in the `viewDidLoad` function of the `ViewController` of the `UITabBarItem` that I would like to stay the same (I had already set an `outlet` between the `UITabBarItem` in Storyboard and the `ViewController`): 
 `myTabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "PickleTabIcon").imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)` 
 This works great, however it is not activated until the `ViewController` is loaded, so a user has to tap on the `TabItem` to load the `ViewController` before this works. 
 I have also tried to access the image of the `UITabBarItem` from the initial `ViewController`, so that the changes go into effect as soon as the application is launched like so: 
 `tabBarController.tabBar.items[2].image` 
 But this throws an error and says that this API has been deprecated. Changing `.image` to `.setImage` doesn't say the API has been deprecated, but it throws an error nonetheless(unrecognized selector). 
 If you have any additional questions, please feel free to ask. Thanks in advance! 
 I am using Swift in XCode 6 Beta 6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tabBar.items` is an array of `AnyObject`s. Try casting the item to `UITabBarItem`

```
var myTabBarItem = tabBarController.tabBar.items[2] as UITabBarItem
myTabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "PickleTabIcon").imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you for the quick response as well.